# How to display line numbers in stack traces on macOS?

Tags: macos, debugging, d

I'm compiling my command-line program using dmd 2.072.1 on OS X El Capitan and trying to get line numbers to show in stack traces when debugging with LLDB. Currently the stack traces look like this:

```
core.exception.RangeError@Level.d(454): Range violation
----------------
4   Game                                0x000000010b108ac1 _d_arraybounds + 97
5   Game                                0x000000010b07f759 Level.__array + 41
6   Game                                0x000000010b0969c4 void Level.Level.GenerateBlocks() + 992
7   Game                                0x000000010b094c32 Level.Level Level.Level.__ctor(Renderer.Renderer, Level.Meshes, Level.Textures, bool, boo
```

Is it possible to see the line numbers with LLDB? If so, how? If not, what alternatives I have when using dmd? I'm developing my D programs with Emacs, but also have Xcode installed for other languages.

Comment: Compile with `-g` See https://dlang.org/dmd-osx.html#switch-g

Comment: I'm already doing that.

Comment: What other flags do you compile with?

Comment: I also tried `-debug` and `-gc`. I just noticed that the first line of my stack trace paste contains the line number, how didn't I see that before :-/ But the question is still valid because other lines don't contain it.

Comment: the first line gets it from the throw line, it is part of Exception's constructor. The later lines are the stack trace itself.... and I don't know enough about Mac OS to know why it isn't working there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on MacOS and had the same problem which I fixed. When I compiled all my C source files into object files I included the -g option. Then when compiling all the object files together to produce the final executable I included the -g option as well. Then lldb showed the proper line number where the error occurred!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).